# How can I modify a WebView in Xamarin.Forms to open links in a browser on the device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

By default links (`<href..>`) Xamarin.Forms WebViews open inside the WebView. Especially in iOS where there's no native backbutton that behavior is unconveniend when opening an Url from the internet.

How do I get Xamarin.Forms to let a browser on the device open the links instead, so that it works in at least Android, iOS and UWP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no built-in property or anything that lets you do this.

However, the `WebView` does have a `Navigating` event handler. You should be able to hook into that, redirect the user to whatever you want and then cancel the original event. Something like this:

```
public void WebView_Navigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Url.StartsWith("file://"))
    {
        return;
    }

    Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));

    args.Cancel = true;
}
```

To hook it up from code:

```
var webView = new WebView();
webView.Navigating += WebView_Navigating;
```

from XAML:

```
<WebView Navigating="WebView_Navigating" />
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.navigating?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: How do I register that function to my webview?

Comment: You could either create an inheritance of the `WebView` if you want to do it everywhere, else; I have updated the question

Comment: This works well on UWP. When I however test it on iOS this results in the html not being displayed. I tried both to do it in xaml and to do it in the code behind.

Comment: When does the HTML not display? Right when you implement this? Or when you navigate?

Comment: It doesn't display right when I implement this in iOS.

Comment: I really want to help you, but I need a bit more information than this. Based on "it doesn't work" it's really hard to proceed. But if I understand correctly the initial loading does not work as well? Probably on iOS the navigated event is also triggered then for non-user initiated navigation. You probably should build in some kind of exception. So, add an extra if-statement that if navigation goes to the root URL that you want to load initially then we skip the Device.OpenUri and Cancel.

Comment: It doesn't get to the stage where there's a navigation event on iOS. As I said above, the html in the WebView won't get displayed on iOS when I add the navigation argument to the WebView.

Comment: Weird, I have created this sample project: https://github.com/jfversluis/WebViewNavigatingSample it does somewhat what you want and I have edited according to my latest comment. The problem is, is that on iOS (not sure for other platforms) it always goes through the navigating event. That means; also when loading scripts from outside the current website. This makes it kind of tedious because you will have to implement some exceptions on when to go outside the app to navigate.

Comment: little update: args.Cancel = false doesn't seem to on Android work when using a custom WebViewRenderer (using Xamairn.Forms 4.5).

Comment: Wow man! that " args.Cancel = true;" save me a lot of headaches. Love you!!

Comment: But, i have the behaviour you describe, i have to implement som exceptions for the scripts that are loading. @GeraldVersluis did you found any way to know if it's a script loading? (PD: I follow you on Youtube, you rocks!).

Comment: this will not working within a listview. on scroll, it will just open the webview without tapping on it