# Force open a new tab in mobile browser from an app

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an app that has a webview in xamarin and shows a web which has links that are configured in this way:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.web.com"> http://www.web.com </a>
```

but they do not work, I suppose this happens because when viewing the web from an app, it is not able to open the link in a new window.
I have also tried window.open without any changes.
How I could configure the link to force open the browser with a new link window.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53704452/how-can-i-modify-a-webview-in-xamarin-forms-to-open-links-in-a-browser-on-the-de

Comment: The event handler does not detect anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should happen on `Android`，if you want to open a new window with browser,you could use `SetWebChromeClient` method for your `WebView` in your custom renderer.

create a custom renderer in android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(AndroidWebView))]
namespace your namespace
{
  class AndroidWebView:WebViewRenderer
  {
      public AndroidWebView(Context context) : base(context)
      {
       
      }

      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
      {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);
          Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MywebviewChrome());
      }

      private class MywebviewChrome : Android.Webkit.WebChromeClient
      {
          public override bool OnCreateWindow(Android.Webkit.WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)
          {
              Android.Webkit.WebView.HitTestResult result = view.GetHitTestResult(); 
              string data = result.Extra; 
              Context context = view.Context; 
              Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView,Android.Net.Uri.Parse(data)); 
              context.StartActivity(browserIntent);

              return false;
          }


      }
  }
}
```

in your forms project xaml :

```
<WebView HeightRequest="800" WidthRequest="600" x:Name="webview" ></WebView>
```

in your page.xaml.cs:

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = @"<a target='_blank' href='http://www.web.com'> http://www.web.com </a>";
webview.Source = htmlSource;
```

Comment: Thanks! The links to another window works perfectly but now I have problems with some input button that should open the mobile file explorer. When the render is active the buttons don't work, if I remove it the buttons work correctly.
What could be the problem?

Comment: @Danteou Could you show the codes of your render ?

Comment: The code is the same as your render, I have not modified anything because I solve the problem of the links, I do not have much experience to modify a custom rencer.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As you supposed, Xamarin.Forms doesn't support opening new tabs / windows.
BUT the Webview component has an event handler called "Navigating" on which you can subscribe to execute code every time the webview tries to open a new page.

```
public void NavigatingEventHandler(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Url.StartsWith("https://"))
    {
        //If you want to open the new window in the OS browser
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri(args.Url));

        //If you want to open the new window inside the webview
        webview.Source = args.Url;

        args.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

XAML:

`<WebView x:Name="webview" Navigating="NavigatingEventHandler" />`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I had thought about it but when I click on the link nothing happens and the event handler does not detect anything.

Comment: Are you sure that the method doesn't execute at all or does the if statement turn false and therefore won't open the page?
Alternatively, you could also try to use the "navigated" event and see if this gets executed.